# Approximation argument in geometric flows

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, parabolic-pde, compactness, flows

I'm studying by myself Mean Curvature Flow and I'm reading the paper "[Interior estimates for hypersurfaces moving by mean curvature](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_153307/component/file_153306/content)" by Klaus Ecker and Gerhard Huisken and I'm stuck in the following theorem:

> $\textbf{Theorem 5.1}$: $M_0 \equiv F_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$  be a locally Lipschitz continuous entire graph over $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the initial value problem $(1)$ has a smooth solution $M_t = F_t(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $t > 0$. Moreover, each $M_t$ is an entire graph over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I didn't understand what approximation argument exactly was used in the the last paragraph of the proof:

> From Corollary $3.5 (ii)$ we then conclude for any integer $m \geq 0$
>
> $$\sup_{B_{R_0}(0) \times [0,T]} \left| D^m w_R \right| \leq c_m,$$
>
> where $c_m = c_m(m,n,R_0,c_0, c_1)$.
>
> We can therefore select a sequence of solutions $(w_{R_k})$ for $R_k \rightarrow \infty$ ($R_k > R_1$ for any $k \geq 2$) s.t. $w_{R_k} \rightarrow w$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ uniformly on $\Omega \times [0,T]$. Since $\Omega$ and $T > 0$ were arbitrary this establishes the existence of a family of entire graphs $M_t = \text{graph} \ w(\cdot, t)$ solving (1) where $w \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty))$. As the second and higher
>   order derivative estimates for $w$ on each compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$  depend only on the initial height and gradient on a slightly larger subset, an approximation argument yields a smooth solution of (1) also for locally Lipschitz initial data.

This last paragraph leads me to think that I need some corollary of Arzela-Ascoli theorem and proceed as the section "4.4 - Curvature explodes" of [this thesis](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nsher/ricciflow.pdf), which teach how construct a global solution. This thesis construct a global solution for the curve shortening flow and the author of thesis states that uniform limit of the subsequence there it's a smooth map and it's clear for me, because this result:

> $\textbf{Theorem A.4.2}$ Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^s$ be a closed bounded set. There is a function $u \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and a sequence $m_j \rightarrow \infty$ with
>
> $$\max_{x,t} \left| \frac{\partial^{p+q}}{\partial x^p \partial t^q} u_{m_j}(x,t) - \frac{\partial^{p+q}}{\partial x^p \partial t^q} u(x,t) \right| \rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ m_j \rightarrow \infty.$$

This theorem can be found on Appendix $4$ of the book "Initial-Boundary Value Problems and the Navier-Stokes Equations" by Heinz-Otto Kreiss and Jens Lorenz, but the problem is that I don't have uniform bounds for $\frac{\partial^{p+q}}{\partial x^p \partial t^q} w_{R_k}$, so I don't know how to proceed here. Is the approximation argument commented by authors really an argument based on Arzela-Ascoli theorem? Anyone can give some details about this argument?

Thanks in advance!